# Fade In Animation on Startup

Tags: angular, animation

I have a div in Angular that I am trying to fade in when my page loads up,

I have followed many tutorials but none of them seem to be working, although I get no errors..

http://jsfiddle.net/r89ud4ez/ 
This what the app currently looks like, The goal is to get the CLI div to fade in when the page loads,

here is my component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { animation, animate, trigger, state, style, transition  } from '@angular/animations';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-intro-cmd-line',
  templateUrl: './intro-cmd-line.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intro-cmd-line.component.css'],
  animations: [
    // the fade-in/fade-out animation.
    trigger('fadeIn', [

      // the "out" style determines the "resting" state of the element when it is visible.
      state('out', style({opacity: 0})),
      // in state
      state('in', style({opacity: 1})),

      transition('out => in', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('in => out', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    ])
  ]
})

export class IntroCmdLineComponent {
state = 'out';
toggleState() {
  this.state = this .state === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
}
}
```

And yes my module.ts has BrowserModuleAnimations imported, so I am not entirely sure why this is not working, With the code I have I would expect my div to start out with 0 opacity due to the fact that I have my trigger set in the container div..

Please help,

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, not sure if I exactly understand this yet, but I think my animation was just so short I could not see it "fade" in,

first thing that was wrong was `<div id="container" [@fadeIn]='out'>` I needed to change 'out' to the name of my state variable,

Here is my final component in case anyone cannot figure out why their animations wont work

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-intro-cmd-line',
  templateUrl: './intro-cmd-line.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intro-cmd-line.component.css'],
  animations: [
    // the fade-in/fade-out animation.
    trigger('fadeIn', [

      // the "out" style determines the "resting" state of the element when it is visible.
      state('out', style({opacity: 0})),
      // in state
      state('in', style({opacity: 1})),

      transition('out => in', animate('1000ms ease-in')),
    ])
  ]
})

export class IntroCmdLineComponent implements AfterViewInit {
state = 'out';

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.state = this.state === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
}
```